# Rails: Passing variable from form to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, rmagick

I have a form, where users can upload a picture and can choose a watermark from a list. The value in the field is then the URL of the watermark (for simplification in development). I need to pass the chosen watermark_url to the model, so that rmagick can add the watermark. I use paperclip for the uploads.

In my model I have the following:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
...

attr_accessor :watermark_url

has_attached_file :picture, :processors => [:watermark], styles: {
thumb: '100x100>',
medium:{
    geometry: '300x300>',
    watermark_path:  Rails.root.join(watermark_url),
    position: "Center"}
}
end
```

watermark_url is a field in the form and in the database (which would not be necessary).
Then I get the following error: undefined local variable or method `watermark_url'.

Am i missing something here?

Thank you in advance for helping!

Comment: Well, we are missing controller code. :)

Comment: The model code is: 
    def create
    @image = current_user.images.build(image_params)
    end
Do I have to pass the watermark_url from the controller to the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your helpful comments I found a solution using lambda to access the instance and its variables. I asked the user for the path of the watermark first, save it and then he uploads his picture.

```
has_attached_file :picture, :processors => [:watermark], :styles => lambda { |a|
{thumb: '100x100>',
medium:{
    geometry: '300x300>',
    watermark_path:  Rails.root.to_s + "/public#{a.instance.watermark_url}",
    position: "Center"}
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `watermark_url` is an instance-level accessor, but you are trying to access it at the class level.  What you are doing is trying to call `Image.watermark_url` but what you have available is `Image.first.watermark_url`.

You cannot do it the way you want to do it (in the attachment definition), because `watermark_url` will be different for each instance of `Image`.  Is `watermark_path` one of the options automatically available from paperclip?

You might have to do something like this:

```
def watermark_url=(path)
  picture.watermark_path = Rails.root.join(path)
end
```

Or something like that.  You'll probably have to tweak it to properly tell paperclip where this specific watermark_path is, but hopefully this gets you started.

This will make it so that if your form submits a `watermark_url` attribute as part of the post params it should automatically get sent to this setter method.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is a custom processor that takes watermark_path as an option.
Tweaking the path in the end should not be a problem once i am able to pass the URL of the watermark to the model.

Comment: I managed to pass the URL to the new method "watermar_url" in my model and can set picture.watermark_path to the right URL. So i have it in the model, but i cannot call it outside this method. What am I doing wrong? This is the method: `def add_url(url);   
 self.watermark_url = url.to_s;
  end`. How can I can call self.watermark_url outside this method?

Comment: Why do you need to make the method `add_url`?  In any case, if `watermark_url=` is a method you'd have to also define the getter method `watermark_url` if you want to have a method to retrieve the set value.  You could store `path` in an instance variable and retrieve it from `watermark_url` if you want (this is how `attr_accessor` works under the hood).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the version of your paperclip but in general, I put the processor in the style, like this :

```
has_attached_file :picture, 
                  styles: { 
                      thumb: { '100x100>', :processors => [:watermark] }, 
                      medium:{
                          geometry: '300x300>',
                          :processors => [:watermark],
                          watermark_path:  Rails.root.join(watermark_url),
                          position: "Center"
                      }
                   }
```

Comment: Everything works fine if i manually set the watermark_url. 
watermark_url = "/system/images/pictures/000/000/027/medium/watermark3.jpg". The problem is if i want to pass the URL from the form.